# Is there a way to add custom colors to the matplotlib cnames dictionary?

Tags: matplotlib, colors

Matplotlib provides a large number of named colors that are identified in a dictionary called cnames.

I'd like to define an additional number of named colors that are part of our corporate palette.

Is there a way to add to the cnames dictionary without editing that file?

Comment: colors are all here: matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/_color_data.py, but I dont think it is a good idea to modify it (add more in your case). You can simply define and declare your own data in your code. check [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d04c8de4a89ab756a137ef146e8542e81041909f/lib/matplotlib/_color_data.py#L1) on github

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve matplotlib's colors mapping dict using [`get_named_colors_mapping`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping.html) and then update it:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors_mapping = mcolors.get_named_colors_mapping()
colors_mapping.update({'my_custom_color': '#12345678'})

plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4], c='my_custom_color')
```

[image]

You may also consider putting you corporate pallette in the `axes.prop_cycle` property in the [matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

Comment: I think that you can modify the prop_cycle in "stylelib". It is too bad that colors can't be added there.